# Regex negate suffix negative lookaround not working

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to set as null the rows that do end with the pattern 'NEW'.

This would be my desired output (the input would just be the first column):

```
           DCALIVE      DESIRED_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------
      DCA_LIVE_NEW                NULL 
     DCA_LIVE_NEWS       DCA_LIVE_NEWS
DCA_LIVE_NO_RECALL  DCA_LIVE_NO_RECALL  
 DCA_LIVE DCA_LIVE   DCA_LIVE DCA_LIVE
```

So far, I've tried a negative lookaround as suggested in other answers, but it does not return values for any of the rows

```
WITH aux ( dcalive ) AS (
    SELECT
        'DCA_LIVE_NEW'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'DCA_LIVE_NEWS'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'DCA_LIVE_NO_RECALL'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'DCA_LIVE'
    FROM
        dual
)
SELECT
    a.*,
    decode(regexp_substr(dcalive, '(?!NEW)$'), NULL, NULL, dcalive) desired_output
FROM
    aux a;
```

Comment: `(?!NEW)$` is a wrong regex pattern that matches any string. You meant to use `(?<!NEW)$` but Oracle regex does not support lookarounds anyway.

Comment: I have also tried [^(NEW)]$, but no luck :(

Comment: Your first sentence and sample data say exactly the opposide.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do you mean?

Comment: @banana_99 . . . "I'm trying to set as null the rows that do not end with the pattern 'NEW'."  You are setting `NULL` the rows that do end in `'NEW'`.

Comment: You're right, editing my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when dcalive not like '%NEW' then dcalive end) as desired_output
```

Regular expressions aren't needed for this.  But you could express this as a regular expression:

```
select (case when not regexp_like(dcalive, 'NEW$)' then dcalive end) as desired_output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
([^N].{2}|.[^E].|..[^W]|^.{0,2})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrixSh/1). *Details*:

- `([^N].{2}|.[^E].|..[^W]|^.{0,2})` - either of

  - `[^N].{2}` - any non-`N` and two chars
  - `|` - or
  - `.[^E].` - any char, non-`E`, any char
  - `|` - or
  - `..[^W]` - any two chars and a non-`W`
  - `|` - or
  - `^.{0,2}` - start of stirng and any zero, one or two chars
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

One option is keeping a ***negative*** *start_position* argument in order to look the characters backwards along with a conditional statement such as

```
SELECT dcalive, DECODE( SUBSTR(dcalive,-3), 'NEW', NULL, dcalive ) AS output
  FROM aux
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3332f6b2f5cb7eace04a32850ec83a75)</kbd>